# asp.net LinkButton OnClick is not firing with href

Tags: asp.net, onclick, href, linkbutton

I have a LinkButton, it works really well, but when I add a href to the LinkButton, it redirects me to the link without firing the OnClick function.

```
<asp:LinkButton target="_blank" ID="ad_main_form"  
    OnClick="ad_button_Click" runat="server"  
    CssClass="ad_main_panel" CausesValidation="False" 
    href="https://stackoverflow.com">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

How to fire OnClick and href together?

Comment: You can leave the page or not, I don't think you can do both.

Comment: Do this: remove the href, load the page in a browser and > view source to see what happens to the linkbutton. Then add a PostBackUrl and reload the browser and > view source again.

Comment: @Jamal this is not none sense, I want to let the user to open a link with href. And track how many times the user clickes that link(anchor tag)   in the back end.   Response.redirect() works but I don't want to do it from server side, I want to open the link in the client side  and track the clickes in the server side

Comment: @Drust-Taib, based on your clarification, see my answer below; Since there is no href, you need to use the OnClientClick() as shown below. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

`LinkButton` has a property with name `PostbackUrl` instead using `href` please use this property.

To avoid all this hassle what I would have done is, call a `Response.Redirect('url')` inside my click handler so it does both the jobs in a cleaner manner.

**Update** 
 Unfortunately you cannot open in new tab using `Response.Redirect()` method, but you can certainly write `javascript` code to open the url in a new tab. See:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "openurl", "window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com' ,'_blank');", true);
```

Alternatively, you can simply do it like this:

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com', '_blank')</script>");
```

Comment: @DrustTaib I think you posted the comment blank.

Comment: @Jamshid Kamaran sorry for the comment it was accident. I have two concerns 1- response.redirect() is doing the same thing, but response.redirect() is from server side. I want to do it from client side.  2-  I want to open the link in a new browser tab, can we do that wit response.redirect()?

Comment: @DrustTaib Please refer to the update in my answer.

Comment: @Jamshid Kamaran   Thank you for your answer. I know it works, but what I am actually seeking for is to open the link in client side, not server side.

Comment: @DrustTaib `window.open` is client side method, You are just injecting javascript onto your page using server and that is because server is being triggered anyway so it is fine if you open a link through server.

Answer (score 0):

asp:LinkButton does not have an href tag.

You need OnClick for server side and OnClientClick for client side

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="ad_main_form"
            runat="server"
            OnClick="ad_button_Click"
            OnClientClick="javascript: window.open('https://stackoverflow.com');">
            Click me
 </asp:LinkButton>
```

C# Code behind:

```
 protected void ad_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // your code
    }
```

You may also handle it this way and supply a custom JavaScript function to OnClientClick(). See the Navigate(url) function. The code-behind stays the same.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourProject.WebForm1" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Navigate(url) {         
        javascript: window.open(url);
    }
</script>  

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="ad_main_form"
            runat="server"
            OnClick="ad_button_Click"
            OnClientClick="Navigate('https://stackoverflow.com')" 
            CausesValidation="False">
            Click me
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
  </form>    
</body>
```

The code has been tested and works fine!